# Is multi-project management possible in OpenProject?

Tags: planning, project-management-style, multi-projects, work-in-progress, openproject

Can I track multiple projects at the same time by using [OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can track multiple projects at the same time by using OpenProject.

From the [OpenProject User's Guide](https://openproject.org/docs/user-guide/projects/):

> OpenProject **does not limit the number of projects**, neither in the Community edition nor in the Enterprise cloud or in Enterprise on-premises edition.